# How to force exit command line bat file when occur download error

Tags: batch-file

Dears
Here is my .bat command line
I use bitsadmin /transfer command download from url.
but got error(like disconnect network...etc) I need continue execute remain command.

But now I can't get achievement... what should I do

```
@echo off
:: Filter updater for HCK and HLK
:::::::::::::::::::::::::: Settings :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Notice: As of July 2015, the HCK and the HLK filter updates are the exact same file, downloaded from the same location!
SET "source=https://sysdev.microsoft.com/member/SubmissionWizard/LegalExemptions/HCKFilterUpdates.cab"

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

SET "destination=C:\FilterUpdates.cab"

if not exist "%DTMBIN%\" (
    echo ERROR: folder "%DTMBIN%"
    echo does not exist! Please verify that you have the controller installed.
    pause
    exit /B 1
)

echo Please make sure that all instances of the Studio are turned OFF!


echo Downloading Filters...
bitsadmin /transfer "Downloading Filters" "%source%" "%destination%"
if errorlevel 1 goto end
echo Extracting...
expand -i "%destination%" -f:UpdateFilters.sql "%DTMBIN%\"
if not errorlevel 0 echo ERROR & exit /B 1
echo Installing...
pushd "%DTMBIN%\"
if not errorlevel 0 echo ERROR & exit /B 1
"%DTMBIN%\updatefilters.exe " /s
if not errorlevel 0 echo ERROR & exit /B 1
popd

:end
exit
```

Comment: If you have not downloaded the file, what are you going to expand?

Comment: Sorry, If download success, will going to expand.
but if download fail, I want to exit the command....

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be caused by the errorlevels generated by `bitsadmin`: some of them are negative values and the test `if errorlevel 1` will be evaluated as false (`if errorlevel n` is true for values greater than or equal to `n`)

You will need to read and test the value of the `errorlevel` variable

```
if not %errorlevel%==0 exit /b 1
```

But sometimes, `bitsadmin` will have errors and will generate a `errorlevel 0`, so, you need to manualy check the status

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:: Filter updater for HCK and HLK
:::::::::::::::::::::::::: Settings :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Notice: As of July 2015, the HCK and the HLK filter updates 
:: are the exact same file, downloaded from the same location!

    SET "source=https://sysdev.microsoft.com/member/SubmissionWizard/LegalExemptions/HCKFilterUpdates.cab"

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    if not exist "%DTMBIN%\" (
        echo ERROR: folder "%DTMBIN%"
        echo does not exist! Please verify that you have the controller installed.
        pause
        exit /B 1
    )

    SET "destination=C:\FilterUpdates.cab"
    if exist "%destination%" del /q "%destination%"

    echo Please make sure that all instances of the Studio are turned OFF!

    echo Creating download task...
    set "taskName=[HCK_FilterUpdater]"

    >nul (
        rem remove task if already present
        bitsadmin /list | find "%taskName%" && bitsadmin /cancel "%taskName%"
        rem create the task
        bitsadmin /create "%taskName%" 
        rem include our file in the task
        bitsadmin /addfile "%taskName%" "%source%" "%destination%"
        rem start the download
        bitsadmin /resume "%taskName%"
    )

    echo Downloading...
    set "exitCode="
    for /l %%a in (1 1 500) do if not defined exitCode for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        bitsadmin /info "%taskName%" 
        ^| findstr /b /l /c:"{"
    ') do for /f "tokens=3,*" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        if "%%~b"=="TRANSFERRED" ( 
            set "exitCode=0"
            >nul bitsadmin /complete "%taskName%"
            echo ... done
        )
        if "%%~b"=="ERROR" ( 
            set "exitCode=1"
            bitsadmin /geterror "%taskName%" | findstr /b /c:"ERROR"
            >nul bitsadmin /cancel "%taskName%"
        )
        if not defined exitCode (
            echo(%%b %%c
            timeout /t 2 >nul 
        )
    )
    if not defined exitCode ( echo TIMEOUT & exit /b 1 )
    if not exist "%destination%" ( echo ERROR & exit /b 1 )

    echo Expanding...
    >nul expand -i "%destination%" -f:UpdateFilters.sql "%DTMBIN%"
    if errorlevel 1 ( echo ERROR & exit /b 1 )

    echo Installing...
    pushd "%DTMBIN%"          || ( echo ERROR & exit /b 1 )
    ".\updatefilters.exe " /s || ( echo ERROR & exit /b 1 )
    popd
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like once command shell is in bitsadmin mode you can't take it out of it. My solution unfortunately is two seperate .bats.